# What is the typical maximum page count for a workbook?

Tags: first-time-author, printing

I am creating a series of student workbooks for use in classrooms. The page count is quite high, so I'll need to divide it into many separate books, but I'm not sure if I need to split it into 3, 5, 10, etc. books. Assuming approximately letter/A4 size, is there a physical limit to the number of pages that printing machinery can bind together, still allowing the pages to be comfortably laid flat for writing?

Comment: I don't think the machinery's limit should be a consideration. If you reach that you're already taxing your poor students' carrying capacity.

Comment: How many pages are you thinking? 500 or 1000 would be possible to print and bind, but there are a lot of other considerations (ease of use, weight, teachers being able to select parts of the series to use, dividing between classes, etc). Those factors would be more important than the limits imposed by binding machines.

Comment: Format is another consideration: Do you use Letter/A4 pages or smaller? Landscape or Portrait?

Comment: What subject? What level of school?

Comment: Why does the subject or school level matter?

Comment: @StuartF I have more around 2500 pages total, so it could be ten 250-page books, five 500 page...thought there might be a typical maximum the machinery can handle. I think if one used a service like Amazon print-on-demand, they probably list a maximum, thinking publishers will be similarly limited.

Comment: Are students expected to complete the whole workbook in a quarter/trimester/semester? Or might that be a useful way to split it up?

Comment: *Why does the subject or school level matter?* Give a 6-yr old a 500 page arithmetic workbook to complete, wait for the parents to helicopter in and douse you with napalm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These results are based on 2000 items on sale at Waterstones with the keyword 'workbook'.

```
Number of pages

mean     128
std       88

min       16
25%       80
50%      104
75%      160
max     1072
```

A size between 100 and 130 is probably a reasonable target for workbook sizes across various subjects and student levels.

Answer (score 1):

Most workbooks we purchased for students were under 100 pages. It's a budget thing. If it costs more than £2 per student, it has to be amazing to justify the cost.

If you want a school to pay for workbooks, you have to provide an overwhelming reason for them not to just photocopy them. Sometimes a publisher would provide something cheaper than we could copy it.

Text books are completely different. For example, a maths classroom can have several thousand pages per year group. These are reusable and so different to a workbook.